# Look for ids in a user table table

Tags: mysql, postgresql, relational-database

I have a `users` table and a pivot table named `user_followers` where I have
`follower_id` and `followed_id` that references the id in the user table.

To get the followers of a user I can get the id of this user and look for the fields where `followed_id` is equal to this specific `user_id`. That's all fine, I get these rows and look for the id of the followers in the `users` table. My question is this if I need to look for the users that match with these ids (that may be many) how can I stop looking for this id when found.

Example: I got these ids: 3,4,9,10,12; I start looking in the user table for any row that has one of those id and when found 3 (for example) I don't want to look for this id any more (because already found) but looking for 4,9,10 and 12 and so on.

Maybe there is something I am missing that solves this problem but I don't know how this works behind the scenes in the database. (I am using Postgres.)

If possible I would like to know how this can be done with Mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about this. A single query does it all:

```
SELECT u.* -- or just the columns you need.
FROM   user_followers AS f
JOIN   users AS u ON u.user_id = f.follower_id
WHERE  followed_id = $1;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Do you recommend me using relational database in this case instead of nosql even If performance is priority? Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: With basic indexes, performance shouldn't be a problem at all with Postgres or MySQL. Depends on exact requirements, of course.